# Async named pipes in windows using trio and python

Tags: python-trio

Is there any way to use async named pipes in trio under windows? I have two applications that should communicate using named pipes. One is running C# (this is not a problem) and the other is running python.

I have tried to dig a little, but have not found any solution yet. The closest I have gotten to related code is this: https://github.com/python-trio/trio/blob/master/trio/tests/test_windows_pipes.py , but currently I can not figure out how to create a named pipe. Does anyone know if it is possible or have a working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately Trio doesn't yet expose a general-purpose interface for working with named pipes: https://github.com/python-trio/trio/issues/824

It shouldn't be terribly difficult to do; we have all the machinery, just not put together into a nice public API.

Would you up for posting on that issue with more details about your use case? The named pipes API has a lot of different pieces and it's hard to find real-world users. Having a concrete example of what a real project needs would be really helpful for figuring out what Trio's API should look like.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you like me to give an use case example in comment or as a new question on Stack or somewhere else?

Comment: @PetarMignon The most convenient way would be to post a comment on the Github Issue I linked above. But if that's difficult for some reason then a comment here would be fine, and I'll copy/paste it to github :-)